# @Html.TextBoxFor able to take Input from barcode scanner BUT not from keyboard input

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, textbox

How would it be possible to make a @Html.TextBoxFor( ) able to take a barcode scanner input but not a keyboard input?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not really possible, since all the barcode scanner does is translate the barcode into readable text. There reaaly is no way to limit what input device you use to enter text.

```
        if (TextBox1.Text.Substring(0,2) == "##" && TextBox1.Text.Substring(TextBox1.Text.Length - 2) == "##")
        {
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(2, TextBox1.Text.Length - 4);
            // or TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("##","");
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: One way to get around it is by adding some meta data to the barcode, and when it is present you can populate the text box with it

Comment: Hmmmm? How would you do this. Thanks!

Comment: Wrap your barcode with some unigue characters, like '##barcodetextexample##', then in the OnChanged event of the text box, if the first and last 2 characters are not ##, delete the text

Comment: How would I wrap my barcode the unique characters? Would that be some sort of programming within the barcode scanner itself?

Comment: @AntLaC But that would still let a user write the same with a keyboard.

Comment: @Mario, but the operators using my software will not know the unique characters. Since the my code will deal with it.

Comment: Thanks @AntLaC, I understand that part, but how will my barcode itself have the ##, that must be barcode programming itself right?

Comment: I don't know about programming the scanner itself, just when you create the barcodes you will wrap your barcoded text with your special characters

Comment: Ohhhhh. Your saying on the barcode text itself. Thanks I appreciat eyour help.

Comment: @AustinTruong So you mean you would delete the *##* part after it's entered by the textbox?

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for :)

Comment: @Mario Yes, you wouldn't want that entered into your database :)

Comment: @AntLaC I'm not getting it, we are talking `@Html.TextBoxFor()` which means MVC and users scanning on the client side. Because a user wouldn't actually be able to work with the server side code. So how would your code help?

Comment: It's the same logic in JavaScript, just attach to it with jQuery with the .blur hook

Answer (score 0):

You will restrict this client-side using JavaScript and validate user input server-side.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, could you please clarify. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Restricting input is not not possible, you can only subscribe on keydown event for window object, accumulate input and if it matches barcode format put it into disabled input.

Some barcode scanners are also able to put user-defined chars at the begin and at the end of the barcode, so you can use that chars to determine barcode range.